# how to set up visual studio for a remote project

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging

Can Visual studio 2019 be used as a local IDE for a solution running on a remote server? specifically i want to create a node.js application on a remote server hosted / provided by my ISP using Vstudio that's running on my local windows machine.  I'd like the builds to run on the remote server.  Is this possible?

To date, I have been connecting via ssh and just using VIM to create my apps.  But I see that VStudio is free and has a lot of support for different types of apps so wanted to give a try.

I launched VStudio and created a new node.js application.  Gave it a name (it was pointing to a local folder)
But then when I tried to do was go under Tools -> options ->Cross platform-> connection manager.
I successfully added a connection to my remote server.  I know the connection worked because it detected that the remote server is running Ubuntu. 
I must be still missing a step because when I try to build, instead of running the build against the remote server, it tries to build locally.

Maybe I can't do this.  Maybe I need a local dev environment... build local and then copy the js files over to the target machine.
But jut thought I'd check

Thanks.